# Is it possible to make a bluetooth calling application in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Someone please help me. I saw a bluetooth chat application. So i wonder is it possible to make a bluetooth calling application.

Comment: what is a "bluetooth calling application"? what are you trying to achieve? what have you tried already?
if you are looking for someone to do the work for you, there are other places for that, and it will cost you some money.

Comment: I am new in software development. I just saw the android bluetooth char application. I just want to know is it possible to make bluetooth calling application (two device connected through bluetooth and then make call to each other). I have no intension to look for someone to do the work for me. I have tried finding my answer in google too. @daniel.gindi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyway, if you haven't done Google yet, then let's do it for you.

So first you have [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) which tells you how it works, and the API involved. Learn it, it is a good reference, and shows you the correct flow.

Then you have [this sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) which actually comes with the SDK and is most likely already on your HDD.

Then when you have some trouble, you can look for other people's questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141668/bluetooth-examples-for-android), and Google knows how to find those in Stackoverflow.

And only after you went through all of these, and you got into trouble, you are more than welcome to come here and ask your question. But remember, make it a **good** question! :-)

Good luck!