# RFCOMM based bluetooth communication between two android devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

For some requirement analysis I want to test a RFCOMM based bluetooth communication between two android devices.

I need to send some 1 MB of data to from Android device 1 and Android device 2 should receive it and display/save the data. I need to do this using Bluetooth SPP (RFCOMM) profile .

Can any one suggest some available app/code to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under the bluetooth documentation for Android Developers. There is the Bluetooth Chat application example which will contain an activity for facilitating the communication between two devices, as well as the service connection. This will be your best example for what you are looking to do.  Here is the link to the Tutorial, you will also find a link to the BluetoothChat application under here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

To see the BluetoothChat application you will first need the Android SDKs, and then you will be able to find the source.

Generally, do some research first, as here is another question of the same sort that has a little more detail, and shows the user made a good attempt first.

[Bluetooth Examples for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141668/bluetooth-examples-for-android)

After following the BluetoothChat application, or the written tutorial on the Android Docs, if you run into bluetooth errors, and other problems with your code. Stack Overflow is definitely the way to go for receiving quality answers to your troubles!